# How to programmatically set application name in Japanese?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Currently I am trying to set application name using

```
net.rim.blackberry.api.homescreen.HomeScreen.setName("これはある");
```

but it throws exception: `IllegalArgumentException`.

Can anyone provide the solution?

I am using Blackberry JDE 5.0.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the IllegalArgumentException? The only other option would be trying the `setName(String name, int int index)` on the [API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/homescreen/HomeScreen.html#setName(java.lang.String)).

Comment: it works fine When i set app name in english using setName() but it throws exception in Japanese

Comment: What does the exception message say?  You've just shown us the exception name.

Comment: My thought is that the API validates the input, perhaps it only accepts English/Euro characters. You probably want to write into the API support and see if that's the case.

Comment: try net.rim.blackberry.api.homescreen.HomeScreen.setName("\u3053\u308C\u306F\u3042\u308B");

Comment: If my solution worked, I'd like to know :) If it helped you, please mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a string encoding problem. Try

`new String(new String("これはある").getBytes("UTF-16BE"), "UTF-16BE");`

It's not pretty but I think that will work.

Here's a link to the Blackberry string spec: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/lang/String.html

By default it's ISO-8859-1 which does not include Japanese characters.

Comment: setName accepts a string, not a byte array, so I think you're looking at the wrong side of the problem.   In BlackBerry development, it is not possible to specify the encoding of your .java files, and it defaults to iso-8859-1, so the compiler is trying to read the source in a character set that doesn't support japanese.   Svetlin's answer in the comments is a better approach here.

Comment: This would create a string from a byte array that would be handed to setName, not just a byte array. A set of Japanese characters are going to be stored as bytes, regardless if the computer interprets them correctly, right? It's just another string (array of bytes) with a length and a null terminator. The compiler shouldn't care.

His approach works, but that's if you only want to set a single string.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work because the **BlackBerry compiler** will interpret the japanese characters in your snippet as **ISO-8859-1**. The problem is fundamentally with the encoding of the java source code.  Calling getBytes and setBytes with the _same_ character encoding won't change the incorrect characters that are parsed by the compiler.   Also, while pretty much irrelevant to this question, Java doesn't use null-terminated representations of strings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is how to get a string represented in your source code into your application with the same characters.  For latin characters, this is pretty straightforward, as we can just put the characters in quotes, and get a string, like "Hello world"

When you go to non-latin, like Japanese, it gets harder.  You can still directly write Japanese in your source code, but you need to make sure your editor and your compiler agree on  an encoding so that the characters can be interpreted correctly.  The Java-SE compiler takes an argument "-encoding" which allows you to specify the encoding of your java source files.
Unfortunately, rapc, the BlackBerry compiler, does not offer an option to specify encoding, even though it is invoking javac itself.  So rapc uses the platform default, which is utf-8 on Linux and OSX and iso-8859-1 on Windows.

The way around this problem is to use a feature of the Java language for parsing strings - unicode escaping.  By entering the six character sequence "\u3053" in a string, the java compiler will parse that number as hexidecimal and use the corresponding unicode code point, solving problems with source file encoding.
So "Hello world" and "\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064" will result in the same strings appearing in your class files.

Because of this, Svetlin's answer from the comments is the right approach here:

```
net.rim.blackberry.api.homescreen.HomeScreen.setName("\u3053\u308C\u306F\u3042\u‌​308B");
```